# uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin::Views::TabbedNavigation (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

> I am getting an error while installing the responsive active admin gem.
>
> I am using https://github.com/ball-hayden/responsive_active_admin this gem to install.
>
> Bundle install works fine and after that when I refresh the url then  I got below error and I have also add require "activeadmin" in config/initializers/active_admin.rb but did not solve my problem, so please help me out Thanks in advance..!!

```
    uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin::Views::TabbedNavigation (NameError)
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-d787029e5523/lib/active_admin/view_factory.rb:7:in `<class:ViewFactory>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-d787029e5523/lib/active_admin/view_factory.rb:4:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-d787029e5523/lib/active_admin/view_factory.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-d787029e5523/lib/active_admin/application.rb:54:in `<class:Application>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-d787029e5523/lib/active_admin/application.rb:5:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-d787029e5523/lib/active_admin/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-d787029e5523/lib/active_admin.rb:65:in `application'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-d787029e5523/lib/active_admin.rb:70:in `setup'
  /var/www/html/sites/parking.localhost/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  /var/www/html/sites/parking.localhost/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

> Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


#responsive activeadmin gem
gem 'responsive_active_admin'
gem 'screencap'
#activeadmin for backend interface
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: Did you add `@import "responsive_active_admin` in `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss` as suggested in gem readme.

Comment: yes I have added @import "responsive_active_admin in app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: @nayiaw I have restart server many times but did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by adding require_relative 'views' in view_factory.rb it solves my problem.
>
> you can find this file in activeadmin gem (/home/198/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@parking/bundler/gems/activeadmin-5536b158bf03/lib/active_admin`)